# How to get rid of error message in reg query in bat file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

Here is the question. I got this script. The registry value doesn't exist. Obviously I will get an error

ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.

But I don't want users to see this. Because I will do something about it. I tried to use redirect it to nul it doesn't work.

hope someone can help. Thanks.

`@ECHO OFF
REG QUERY HKLM\SOFTWARE\MyApplication\Resources /v %REGVAL_INSTALLDIR% >nul ||( GOTO NOTFOUND )
:NOTFOUND
   REM I'll DO SOMETHING ELSE
exit /b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
REG QUERY HKLM\SOFTWARE\MyApplication\Resources /v %REGVAL_INSTALLDIR% >nul 2>nul ||( GOTO NOTFOUND )
:NOTFOUND
   REM I'll DO SOMETHING ELSE
exit /b
```

error messages are printed in `2` stream so you need to redirect it also to `nul`